# Update button error react framework

Tags: reactjs

Please if you can check this code to find the error why it doesn't save when i click the Update button. I have a list with product i can add, modify and delete. 
When i click Edit to modify it opens a new form with properties to be modified; but it doesn't save the modification. 
How can i solve it?
Here's the code of the project: https://github.com/dkapexhiu/product-management
The code for this modification is at src/Products.js and ProductsRow.js.
Any help is welcomed.

ProductRow.js

```
editItem(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.editProduct(this.props.product.id, this.input.value);
    this.toggleState();
}
```

Product.js

```
updateProduct(newValue){
    this.setState({
        currentProduct:newValue.target.value,
    });
}

editProduct(product, newValue) {
    var products = this.state.products;
    var product = products[product.id];
    product['name']= newValue;
    this.setState({
      products
    })
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question rather than linking to it.

Comment: Yes, excuse me. If you can help ..

Comment: Looks like it's because you're not finding the right product? You are using `products[product.id]`. That means if the project id is `63` you will try to grab the item at the 63rd index in the products array. What does `this.state.products` look like? You may need to using something like `_.find` from lodash: `const product = _.find(products, { id: product.id});`

Comment: So please how to resolve it? Can you rewrite the code for fixing?